# How to test if a 3-bit bus has the first bit set on 1 - verilog

Tags: testing, verilog, bus, icarus

I'm trying to find out how could I check if a 3-bit bus has the msb set on 1, i.e. 1xx.
When I check bus==3'b1xx nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Check `if(bus[2])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the expression you wrote can only be (1'b0) or (1'bx), which are both considered false for an `if` statement branch.

Assuming you declared the bus as `wire [2:0] bus;` you can check it using `bus[2] == 1'b1`

Now in SystemVerilog, you can do a wildcard match using `bus ==? 3'b1xx` which treats the RHS X's as don't cares. X's on the LHS are treated the same as `==`.